# Collections.Counter add zero count elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter

I have this code to analyse the `node.properties` json dict for my data:

```
def summarise_all_model_properties(
    all_nodes: list
) -> defaultdict[str, Counter[str]]:

    propdicts = defaultdict(Counter)
    for node in all_nodes:
        propdicts[node.model_type].update(
            k for k in node.properties.keys() if node.properties[k]
        )

    return propdicts
```

Which correctly counts every time a `node.properties[propertyName]` is not an empty/falsey value. This gives a list of all non-blank properties and their counts, grouped by `node.model_type`

However I would also like to know any node properties that exist but are empty and report 0 in `Counter` e.g. right now I have (in pseudocode)

```
foo.properties = {"a": "something!", "b": '', "c": 123}
bar.properties = {"a": "", "b": '', "c": "something else!"}

all_nodes = [foo,bar]

Counter({"a": 1, "c": 2})
```

but I want to include b even though it's always empty in the data

```
Counter({"a": 1, "b":0, "c": 2})
```

#### Update

This is because I have some code later that prints the properties + count of non-blank usages to a table with 2 columns, and I do not know all the property names ahead of time (they come from reading a json file)

```
for model_type, counter in summarise_all_model_properties(all_nodes).items():
    for propname, count in counter.items():
        csv.writerow(model_type, propname, count)
```

Answer (score 2):

A `Counter` acts just like a dictionary.  You can always set a default value after the counts have been collected.

```
c = Counter({"a": 1, "c": 2})
c.setdefaults('b', 0)
c
# returns:
Counter({'c': 2, 'a': 1, 'b': 0})
```

This is has the benefit of also not over-writing the count for `b` if it ever gets included.

Comment: What if I don't know all the property names ahead of time to hardcode - is there a way to do setdefaults dynamically without going over the data twice - once to get the property names and set default, the second to count usage based on my filter condition?- (see update at end of question)

Comment: Use `dict.setdefault` / an inner defaultdict instead of a counter, and create an entry every time?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
propdicts[node.model_type].update(
    k for k in node.properties.keys() if node.properties[k]
)
```

to

```
propdicts[node.model_type].update(
    {k: 1 if v else 0 for k, v in node.properties.items()}
)
```